# How do I compare and highlight the matches from two columns in Excel without replacement?

Tags: excel, compare, highlight, replace

I have two columns of data in an Excel spreadsheet. I have to see that every value in Column A has a match in Column B. I understand that two columns can be compared and highlighted in Conditional Formatting using the Match function.

The problem is that the the Match function in Conditional Formatting does not exclude previously matched and highlighted values from the list for future comparisons. For example...

A: 1, 1, 2, 3

B: 2, 3, 1, 0

If using the Match function in Conditional Formatting, both "1" values in Column A would be highlighted because it sees that there is a "1" in column B. I need the columns to match one-to-one. So once a value is found to have a match in the other column, that match is excluded from the comparisons for the rest of the function's execution. If possible, I would prefer doing this entire project without the use of Macros. But if Macros are necessary, I am perfectly fine using them.

Comment: I am curious what you want to do with the other matches. Nothing, or something different?

Comment: The other matches are indicative of an error by someone punching the numbers in. This is typically resolved by calling and asking "did you mean X instead of Y." It is most often simply missing the correct key.

Comment: If that is the cause for the duplicates, and not really knowing your data entry system, but perhaps you could do some simple data validation to not allow them, asking a question before the entry is allowed. prevent rather than fix

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in column A and B you could try this:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)-COUNTIF(B:B,A1)
```

Place the formula in C1 and then copy down the entire column.
It will test every value in Column A to see if it appears the same amount of times as in column B and show how many more times it appears in Column A.

To even it out, you can also use

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)-COUNTIF(B:B,B1)
```

In column D whichc would test the values in Column B.

Here's how it would look using your sample data plus 1 additional row just to have a negative number:

```
A   B   Test A  Test B
1   2      1       0
1   3      1       0
2   1      0       1
3   0      0       0
0   4      0      -1
```

Definitely not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Edit:
Or you could use conditional formatting with [indirect referencing](http://mediaczar.com/blog/2008/12/referring-to-this-cell-using-excel-conditional-formatting/) to refer to the current cell:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE))=COUNTIF(B:B,INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE))
```

Applying this conditional formatting to column A would highlight any value that appears the same amount of times in each column.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Daniel! I am using the indirect referencing you provided!